# How to determine frame content

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, frame

I set frame content using `MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2))`. How to get information which Page is currently displaying. I want to make something like address bar.

Comment: OP what you accepted as an answer is actually quite different from what you asked. "How to get information which Page is currently displaying" is not remotely close to trying obtain the instance of the Page currently being displayed on the Frame.

Comment: If you performed the cast with a different type than the one that's currently being displayed on the frame, it's not going to work. So, you need to know exactly the type of the Page which is currently being displayed, which goes against the premise in your question. 
If this was your intentions from the start, I suggest that you update your question to something that better fits the accepted answer.

Comment: @AndréB I also agree. Looking back at what has been asked, I think more clarificaiton on the problem needing to be solved would help here.

Reading the last sentence, if OP is looking to create something like an address bar, the instance of the page itself wouldn't give you much unless the result is to get an element from the page to update th address bar. 

In this situation, I would always recommend against this and would point in the direction of using an MVVM pattern and accessing this information in the view-model and services, not the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the actual instance of Page2 from your Frame, you can do that as follows:

```
var frame = MyFrame;
var page2 = frame.Content as Page2;
```

The content property of your Frame is the UI element representing the content displayed currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the type which is currently being displayed on your frame, by checking out the `CurrentSourcePageType`and the `SourcePageType` properties of your Frame instance.

The difference between them is explained by *Microsoft* the following way:

> CurrentSourcePageType and SourcePageType are normally the same value.
>   However, if the frame calls Navigate and the navigation is still in
>   progress, the CurrentSourcePageType is the value before the navigation
>   and the SourcePageType is the value being navigated to.